# Screen rotation adapter notifyDataSetChanged not working

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with updating RecyclerView when rotating the screen. By clicking on fab button I'm showing dialog fragment with input fields. Then when I'm rotating the screen and saving data my  RecyclerView is not updating. I'm setting adapter in onCreate method. I should rotate once more in order to see fresh data. How can solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

```
dataSource = new MyBusinessDataSource(this);

        try
        {
            dataSource.openForRead();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlEx)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MyBusinessMainActivity.this, R.string.sqlite_exception, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        categories = dataSource.getAllCategories();

        adapter = new CategoriesAdapter(this, categories);
        rv_list_cats.setAdapter(adapter);
        dataSource.close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override your onConfigurationChanged method in your activity or fragment and update your data there. Like.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(adapter!=null)
    {
        categories = dataSource.getAllCategories();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Also if you are not using the ScreenConfig property in your manifest use that looks like this.

```
   android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: It's not being called.

Comment: Sorry .. just mixed two words in my answer. check the updated answer and add the config properties in your activity tag of manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added it but still not working. Oh sorry will update right now and try.

Comment: Are you using cursorLoader with recyclerView ?

Comment: That worked Thank You!. No I'm not using cursorLoader.

Comment: Ok. There was another turnaround if you were using Cursorloader.. Anyway. You are welcome,